# Error uploading photo to Appcelerator ACS using Trigger.io

Tags: appcelerator, trigger.io

I'm trying to upload a photo to Appcelerator Cloud Services (ACS) storage using Trigger.io.

I can't figure out the correct syntax to use for the file object.
I'm getting an error "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]"

Here's my relevant code:

```
$("#photograph-record").on("click", function(){
    forge.file.getImage({source:"camera", width: 280, height: 280},function(file) {

    var data = {
          photo: file  //the ID of file input control
        };

    sdk.sendRequest('photos/create.json', 'POST', data, callback);
    });
});
```

Here's the Docs for the ACS Photo class - http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/api/v1/photos/create

Required Parameters - photo: the attached binary file

Since it needs to be a binary I tried "photo: forge.file.string(file)" (http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/file.html#modules-file), but got an error on the Appcelerator side "Photo parameter required for photo upload".

I have no problem passing the image into my App page views using forge.file.url, so I know there's no problems with the file object, it's just figuring out the correct syntax to pass it as a binary to the sdk.sendRequest call.

Any ideas on what I need to be passing in the data variable to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Appcelerator docs are pretty good here - it looks like they're expecting a POST parameter called `photo` which contains the binary image data.

To do that using our [request module](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/request.html):

```
$("#photograph-record").on("click", function(){
    forge.file.getImage({source:"camera", width: 280, height: 280},function(file) {
        file.name = 'photo'; // the magic    
        forge.request.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/photos/create.json',
            files: [file],
            success: function () { ... },
            error: function () { ... }
        });
    });
});
```

I don't see a way to use their JS library here, because they're expecting you to pass in the id of a HTML form element to get data from, but we're interacting with the camera or gallery directly...

Comment: Thanks James, I'll try that and see how it goes.

I'll just need to figure out the proper way to pass my ACS credentials with the forge.request.ajax call. 

Hopefully it's just like the REST call: https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/photos/create.json?key=<YOUR APP APP KEY>

Comment: Got it figured out finally. Had to add the session_id to the URL to authenticate the user and add the POST type.
`forge.request.ajax({
              url: 'https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/photos/create.json?key=app_key_goes_here&_session_id=session_key_goes_here,
              type: 'POST',
              files: [file],
              success: function () { alert('Success'); },
              error: function (data) { alert('Error' + data.content ); }
          });`